# Adding jQuery to input dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a script that uses jQuery that find an input on an html like so:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
 $('[name="date[1][name]"]').datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

I want it to call many inputs such as:

```
date[1][name]
date[2][name]
date[3][name]
etc
```

How do I get the script to add the datapicker to all those inputs without doing it manually? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you test on a custum attribute/class or type=datepicker ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to give them all a common class and then use the class as the selector?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML for the inputs?

Comment: Try `$('input[name="date[1]"],input[name="date[2]"],input[name="date[3]"]').datepicker();` you can chain multiple elements comma separated in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a loop around your code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('[name="date[' + i + '][name]"]').datepicker();
}
```